# Getting the Event ID After creating Event with google spreadsheet/calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I've written a script for creating events for Google calendar over a form and spreadsheet.
Is there a possibility to get the Event ID right after creating the event?
Would like to save it in spreadsheet so I can change or delete the event if needed...

Comment: Can you share what you have now? Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can access an event's Id by calling a `getId()` method on a `CalendarEvent` class instance (assuming you create an event by means of a `CalendarApp` service). If, on the other hand, you make an `http` request to Calendar API (e.g. `insert`), you can generate an id, pass it as a request body property `id` (there are three requirements: base32hex encoding, 5<=id.length<=1024, must be unique) and persist its value however you see fit.

This is a very simplistic example to illustrate the second approach (the example assumes you've enabled Calendar API in advanced services under "Calendar" name):

```
/**
 * Test for created event;
 * @returns {Object} requested event;
 */
function getEvent() {
  var id = 'eventid1';
  var event = Calendar.Events.get('primary', id);
  Logger.log(event);
  return event;
}

/**
 * Inserts event (for example simplicity, hardcoded Id);
 */
function insertEvent() {

  var id = 'eventid1';

  var start = new Date()
      start.setHours(21);

  var end = new Date()
      end.setHours(22);

  var tz = 'America/Los_Angeles';

  var event = {
    start : {
      dateTime : start.toISOString(),
      timeZone : tz    
    },
    end : {
      dateTime : end.toISOString(),
      timeZone : tz   
    },
    id : id
  };

  Calendar.Events.insert(event, 'primary');
}
```

Hope any of the two solutions will help, otherwise, please do provide a sample of your code that creates an event!